# Mostrar palabras en orden alfabetico sin duplicarse de una tabla MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es mostrar alfabeticamente y de forma aleatoria una palabra segun como comienza alfabeticamente, por ejemplo si tengo agua,alabarda y agujero deberia mostrar solo una de esas 3, lo mismo con las que siguen, para completar el alfabeto que tengo que va de A hasta la D.
Intente hacerlo con este codigo:

```
SELECT distinct left(contenido_palabra,1) as letra,contenido_palabra from palabras order by letra;
```

Pero el mismo me muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de mostrar lo que pido mediante alguna funcion o procedimiento?.

Answer (score 0):

Existe una función en mysql que se llama RAND() y que podrías probar cambiando el order by

```
ORDER BY RAND()
```

O

```
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Tienes que tener en mente que el uso de RAND puede relantizar una consulta y todo esto sería más fácil si por código (php, js, etc) haces un select y lo guardas en un array que ordenas o modificas sin cargar la base de datos